# How to fix 404 error on DJANGO for external URL

Tags: django

I am using DJANGO for the first time to make a project for a website. I am getting a 404 error message.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/external/
Using the URLconf defined in firstwebsite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin
output [name='script']
external

The current path, external/, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Views.py

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    import requests 
    import sys
    from subprocess import run,PIPE
    
    def button(request):
    
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    def output(request):
        data=requests.get("/Users/myname/PycharmProject/ex2.py/coders.py")
        print(data.text)
        data=data.text
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'data':data})
    
    def external(request):
        inp= request.POST.get('param')
    
        out= run([sys.executable,'/Users/myname/tester/tester/test.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
        print(out)
    
        return render(request, 'home.html',{'data1':out})
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Python button script
            </title>
        </head>
            <body>
                <button onclick="location.href='{% url 'script' %}'">Execute Script</button> <hr>
                {% if data %}
                
                {{data | safe}}
    
                {% endif %}
            <form action="/external/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                Input Text:
                <input type="text"name="param" required><br><br>
                {{data_external}}<br><br>
                {{data1}}
                <br><br>
                <input type='submit' value="Execute External Python Script">
            </form>  
            </body>
    
    </html>
```

URL Configuration

```py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.button),
        path('output', views.output, name="script"),
        path('external', views.external),
    ]
```

```py
    import sys
    import datetime
    
    time=datetime.datetime.now()
    
    output="Hi %s current time is %s " % (sys.argv[1],time)
    
    print(output)
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6Xi7x4G7yg&t=0s

Answer (score 0):

```
urls.py
app_name = 'tester'
urlpatterns = [
    path('external', views.external,name='external'),
    # This name you can change and add to the URL in template
]

HTML
 <form action="{% url 'tester:external' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Input Text:
    <input type="text" name="param" required><br><br>
    {{data_external}}<br><br>
    {{data1}}
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value="Execute External Python Script">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

```
Add app_name in urls.py (Adding name space is a best practice)
app_name = 'tester'. 
If you do not wish to use namespace, do not add app_name in urls.py and use url `as {% url 'external' %}`
```

In your case the issue was you have to change,

1. The `/external/ to /external` in the form action
2. OR `path('external', external,name='external') to path('external/', external,name='external')` in urls.py

Issue of manually typing url `<form action="/externalURL" method="post">`
is django not throwing an error.

Why to use django default way `<form action="{% url 'externalURL' %}" method="post">` because django throws error as if URL not found

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'externalURL' not found. 'externalURL' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: hey thank you I tried this and go a new error NoReverseMatch at /
'tester' is not a registered namespace. <form action="{% url 'tester:external' %}" method="post"> tester is my project name, should something else be there